# Dispose Bitmap after showing it in a picturebox control

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, garbage-collection, picturebox

I would like to know why the garbage collector cannot keep track of the amount of memory used by the unmanaged part of a bitmap and release this resource when needed.

I discovered it when a loop in a background thread called the following function causing an exception after a while:

```
    private delegate void setImageCallback();
    private void showFrame()
    {
        if (pboxCam.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new setImageCallback(showFrame));
        }
        else
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(getBitmapFromCam());
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.DrawRectangle(RectanglePen, 10, 10, 50, 30);
            g.Dispose();
            pboxCam.Image = bmp;
        }
    }
```

Then I tried to release bmp at the end of the function, but the picturebox doesn’t show up the image anymore.
The solution below does work, but there is something I don’t like. What do you think?

```
    Bitmap bmp;

    private delegate void setImageCallback();
    private void showFrame()
    {
        if (pboxCam.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new setImageCallback(showFrame));
        }
        else
        {
            if (bmp!=null) bmp.Dispose();
            bmp = new Bitmap(getBitmapFromCam());
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.DrawRectangle(RectanglePen, 10, 10, 50, 30);
            g.Dispose();
            pboxCam.Image = bmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *causing an exception* is not helpful. What exception? pose the message, exception name and stacktrace

Comment: Do you set the `PictureBox` in loop?

Comment: `but there is something I don’t like` What you dont like, whats happening?

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, you are right. I thought it was obvious that it was an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan, the function itself is called in a loop which retrieves frames from a camera

Comment: @manuchao, it works perfectly. It's only I've never seen disposing an object at the beginning of a function and before allocating a new instance of it. I just wondered if it was for a reason

Comment: You're sure that is `OutOfMemoryException` or `Win32Exception`? because Gdi leaks causes exception of latter. and there is no reason to get `OutOfMemoryException` since you don't have references for them anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it right. The GC is tracking the `Bitmap` object, and it will release it eventually. The key word being "eventually".

To reclaim the managed `bmp` instance, it first has to run into memory pressure. That occurs at about 1 MiB for gen-0 collections or so. I'm not sure about the precise number, but the key element is that it's a lot. You're going to have thousands of bitmaps, if not more, before you even get to gen-0 collection - and you usually need a gen-2 to execute finalizers (though take that with a grain of salt, I have no idea where I found that information).

Even when the GC does eventually run (in practice, you'll run out of memory long before that), it will start executing the finalizers on a separate thread. It has no idea about the unmanaged resources, so it has to rely on the finalizer code, which it runs serially. It has no idea how much unmanaged memory is allocated at all, and cannot figure that in its memory checks.

So, the key thing is to always run `Dispose` on `IDisposable` objects. The GC might not even get the chance to start the finalizers before you run out of memory, because it's only induced by *managed* memory pressure. It has no idea about the unmanaged memory (if any). That's not the GCs fault, it really can't tell - after all, in your precise case, the memory is shared. The GC can't know if it even *should* release that memory - that's up to the `Bitmap.Finalize` to decide.

That's also the reason why you really want to make everything that uses any `IDisposable` or unmanaged memory, also `IDisposable` - to make sure the caller can release the native resource as soon as possible.

This doesn't apply just to unmanaged *memory* - waiting for the GC to dispose of eg. a file handle or a socket connection is a bad idea, since you really don't want to hold those longer than necessary.

Comment: I agree with you, but op says it throws `OutOfMemoryException` am skeptical about that:(

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I've expanded my answer to hopefully answer your skepticism :)

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, I've a print of the screen with the exception, but it's better not showing here. Just believe me :) The line where it occurs is Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(getBitmapFromCam());

Comment: My question is why it was not implemented a mechanism to add pressure to GC equal to the amount of memory allocated for the pixel data (which can be easily calculated)?

Comment: @GiuseppeDini .NET doesn't know that. GDI+ handles that, and that's a native, unmanaged library. Even if it did, it's not managed memory pressure, so it has nothing to do with the GC whatsoever. It doesn't even necessarily have to allocate anything, or the same bitmap data may be used by a completely different application. Unmanaged is just that - unmanaged. You have no real tracking of the memory. I for one am quite glad the GC doesn't guess :) The fact that the native handles are wrapped in managed handles saves you from leaks (nice), not running out of memory (your fault).